# What causes this code to output multiple lines (mips assembly)?

Tags: algorithm, assembly, mips, bresenham

Note: Please do not downvote this newbie's question to aid learning. Its rather disheartening for someone asking for help to be downvoted.

Hi I have been trying to implement bresenham's algorithm in mips assembly, however I was using an incomplete algorithm i.e. not including error etc. I stumbled upon someone's mips assembly code which uses the algorithm however I do not understand what in the code makes the program output multiple lines. Is main_for part of what's causing the code to output multiple lines?

```
.data  
bitmap :    .word 0x10040000
bitmap_x_max :  .word 256 # width in pixels
bitmap_y_max :  .word 256 # heigh in pixels
s_zero :    .float 0.0
s_meio :    .float 0.5
s_neg_one :     .float -1.0
w_one:      .word 1
w_neg_one:  .word -1
w_two:      .word 2
w_68:       .word 256
.text

#valores fixos em cada chamda, values fixed 
li   $a0, 32    
li   $a1, 32
addi $sp, $sp, -4
li $t0, 0x000FFFFF 
sw $t0, 0($sp)# coloca cor na pilha, saves colour to memory


move $t0, $zero #i = 0
lw   $s0, w_68 #final do loop
main_for:
    slt $t1, $t0, $s0 #atual < máximo?  
    beqz $t1, main_for_end

    li   $a0, 128
    li   $a1, 128
    move $a2, $t0
    li   $a3, 0

    jal desenhaLinha_bom




    addi $t0, $t0, 32
    j main_for

main_for_end:   

li $t0, 0x00000FFF 
sw $t0, 0($sp)# coloca cor na pilha, saves colour to stack?


move $t0, $zero #i = 0
lw   $s0, w_68 #final do loop





main_for2_end:  


li $v0, 10
syscall

SetPixel:
#recebe posicaoo x em $a0, y em $a1 e cor em $a2
# x position is in $a0, y position is in $a1, colour is in $a2
# pinta o bit_map com a cor indicada no pixel indicado, paint bit_map with colour indicated

addi $sp, $sp, -8
sw   $t0, 4($sp)
sw   $t1, 0($sp)

lw $t0, bitmap # endereco base, base address
lw $t1, bitmap_x_max# x_max: n de colunas maxima, bitmap width

# t1 = y*n_linhas
mult $a1, $t1
mflo $t1 # t1 = y*colunas

# t1 = y*n_colunas + x
add $t1, $t1, $a0 # t1 = y*n_colunas + x
sll $t1, $t1, 2 # t1 = 4*(y*n_colunas + x)
add $t1, $t1, $t0# t1 = base + 4*(y*n_colunas + x)

sw $a2, 0($t1)


lw   $t0, 4($sp)
lw   $t1, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 8

jr $ra



desenhaLinha_bom:
#desenha uma linha de (x0,y0)=(a0,a1) ate (x1,y1)=(a2,a3)
#a cor esta em 0($sp) , colour is at 0($sp)
#altera fp! CUIDADO!!!, be careful using $fp

move $fp, $sp # guarda ponto inicial da pilha, save starting point
addi $sp, $sp, -52 # abre espaco para 5 variaveis a serem restauradas
sw $t4, 48($sp)
sw $t3, 44($sp)
sw $t2, 40($sp)
sw $t1, 36($sp)
sw $t0, 32($sp)
sw $s6, 28($sp)
sw $s5, 24($sp)
sw $s4, 20($sp)
sw $s3, 16($sp)
sw $s2, 12($sp)
sw $s1, 8($sp)
sw $s0, 4($sp)
sw $ra, 0($sp)

    # register           | variable
# | registrador |   variável    |
# | t0      |   x_atual     |   
# | t1      |   y_atual     |
# | t2      |   erro_atual  |   
# | t3      |   erro_2|aux1 |
# | t4      |   aux2        |
# | s0      |   cor     |
# | s1      |   x_final     |
# | s2      |   y_final     |
# | s3      |   dx      |
# | s4              dy|-dy      |
# | s5      |   sx      |
# | s6      |   sy      |


lw $s0, 0($fp) #carrega a cor em s0, colour is in $s0

#calcula DX e DY, calculate dx and dy
sub $s3, $a2, $a0 #s3 = x1 - x0
abs $s3, $s3 #s3 = dx = |x1 - x0|

sub $s4, $a3, $a1 #s2 = y1 - y0
abs $s4, $s4 #s4 = dy = |y1 - y0|

# if x0 < x1 then sx := 1 else sx := -1
slt $t0, $a0, $a2 # t0 = (x0 < x1)?
beq $t0, $zero, desenhaLinha_if1_else  
desenhaLinha_if1_then:
    lw $s5, w_one
    j desenhaLinha_if1_exit
desenhaLinha_if1_else:
    lw $s5, w_neg_one
desenhaLinha_if1_exit:

# if y0 < y1 then sy := 1 else sy := -1
slt $t0, $a1, $a3 # t0 = (y0 < y1)?
beq $t0, $zero, desenhaLinha_if2_else  
desenhaLinha_if2_then:
    lw $s6, w_one
    j desenhaLinha_if2_exit
desenhaLinha_if2_else:
    lw $s6, w_neg_one
desenhaLinha_if2_exit:

sub $t2, $s3, $s4 #  err := dx-dy

lw $t0, w_neg_one
mult $t0, $s4
mflo $s4 # s4 = -dy

move $t0, $a0 # t0 = x = x0 (estado inicial)
move $t1, $a1 # t1 = y = y0 (estado inicial)
move $s1, $a2 # s1 = x1 (x_fim)
move $s2, $a3 # s2 = y1 (y_fim)



  desenhaLinha_for1:
    #plot(x0,y0)
    move $a0, $t0
    move $a1, $t1
    move $a2, $s0
    jal SetPixel # plot(x_atual, y_atual)

    #testa saida do loop
    sub $t3, $s1, $t0 #t3 = x_final - x_atual
    sub $t4, $s2, $t1 #t4 = y_final - y_atual
    add $t3, $t3, $t4 #se (x_atual == x_final) && (y_atual == y_final), t3 =                 0
    beqz $t3, desenhaLinha_for1_end # if x0 = x1 and y0 = y1 exit loop

    lw $t3, w_two
    mult $t3, $t2
    mflo $t3 #t3 = err2 = 2*Erro_atual 

    slt $t4, $s4, $t3 # -dy < err2 ?
    beqz $t4, desenhaLinha_for1_if1_end
    desenhaLinha_for1_if1_then:
        add $t2, $t2, $s4 # t2 = erro_atual = #erro_atual + (-dy)
        add $t0, $t0, $s5 # x_atual += sx
    desenhaLinha_for1_if1_end:

    slt $t4, $t3, $s3 # err2 < dx ?
    beqz $t4, desenhaLinha_for1_if2_end
    desenhaLinha_for1_if2_then:
        add $t2, $t2, $s3 # t2 = erro_atual = erro_atual + dx
        add $t1, $t1, $s6 # y_atual += sy
    desenhaLinha_for1_if2_end:

    j desenhaLinha_for1 #loop




desenhaLinha_for1_end:



lw $t4, 48($sp)
lw $t3, 44($sp)
lw $t2, 40($sp)
lw $t1, 36($sp)
lw $t0, 32($sp)
lw $s6, 28($sp)
lw $s5, 24($sp)
lw $s4, 20($sp)
lw $s3, 16($sp)
lw $s2, 12($sp)
lw $s1, 8($sp)
lw $s0, 4($sp)
lw $ra, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 52

jr $ra
```

Comment: Down-voters please comment on what would make this a better (good enough) question.

Comment: Can you figure out what `jal…sw $ra, X($sp)` and `lw $ra, X($sp)…jr $ra` do? Can you make head or tail of the Portuguese comments/names?

Comment: @greybeard the jal desenhaLinha_bom  is basically the program calling the part of the code that contains the bresenham's algorithm. Everything  else with desenhaLinha_bom basically is part of the loops involved in the bresenham's algorithm. The sw... Part is basically memory being allocated to different registers and the lw part I believe is the memory being placed back in the stack. I'm a newbie self learner so I hope I explained it accurately.

Comment: @greybeard I will edit to try to make the comments in english

Comment: (`jal` _jump and link_ jumps to the effective address, placing the return address in general register 31 (some assembler provide alias/equivalenced name _ra_ (return address…)); `sw $ra, 0($sp)` places this at offset 0 relative to whatever register _sp_ has been aliased/equivalenced to (29 by convention). Together with restoring _ra_ from the stack(, re-adjusting the stack pointer) and jumping to the value in that register (`lw $ra, 0($sp)…jr $ra`), this is the MIPS call/return sequence. (My MIPS manual is old enough to read _Jump And Lind_.))

Comment: @greybeard wow :) thanks a lot. Thoroughly explained but do you what in the code would cause it to output multiple lines? Struggling to learn MIPS here

Comment: I'm not sure how much attention MIPS assembly questions l get there, but there is a Portuguese language Stack Overflow: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

offtopic: you shouldn't be learning MIPS by using Bresenham's algorithm, start with something smaller or it is going to be difficult to help you when you need an explanation of what individual instructions are doing.

ontopic:
Yes you are correct, main_for is where the the code is drawing multiple lines, w_68 is controling how many lines (how many times the loop is being executed). w_68 is stored in $s0 and compared in every loop with $t0 (initialized in 0 and being incremented while it is less than $s0 (w_68).

desenhaLinha_bom is where the line is being drawn (actual Bresenham). Haven't checked the full algorithm implemented there, but if it's ok it is an improved version of Bresenham's algorithm (not the naive one, will be harder to grasp since it is merging octants in a single loop)

Hope it helps!

Comment: ok i will try to start with something smaller. I was just trying understand why my previous code  at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106798/error-in-mips-assembly-code-bresenham-line-drawing-algorithm?noredirect=1#comment59859562_36106798          didn't work. Thanks sergio you and graybeard have helped me understand what's going on in the code :))

Comment: i meant you and greybeard

Answer (score 1):

(There got to be more effective ways to learn (MIPS) assembly than trying to figure out scantily commented source listings.)

Lets assume *labels* are candidates for *entry points*, and routines do what their names suggest.
There `SetPixel: x/y position in $a0/$a1, colour in $a2`, getting called from `desenhaLinha_bom: line from (x0,y0)=(a0,a1) to (x1,y1)=(a2,a3), colour is at 0($sp)` (drawing a single line by setting individual PIXELs) (according to cjj20's comments, cjj20 figured out as much).
`desenhaLinha_bom` only gets called in the code from the fist `.text` (where execution presumably starts) to `li $v0, 10
syscall`, which probably terminates it; in between a label called `main_for:` and a backwards jump to it. At the head of this ("main") loop, `t0` (initialised to 0 - current_x?) gets compared to `s0/w_68` (for equality, which looks anything but defensive). After drawing the line, `t0`/current_x gets incremented by 32, which may or may not make it equal to `s0/w_68`.
(So I think cjj20 correct in assuming `main_for` responsible for multiple lines.)
(You may notice at least two entirely similar answers - within minutes, after hours.)

Comment: hah i suspected that 32  and w_68 was important in creating multiple lines. Thanks so much :)) !